# Triple integral on a set E

Tags: real-analysis

I have the set $$E=\left\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2+z^4 \le 4,{1 \over 3}(x^2+y^2) \le z^2 \le 3(x^2+y^2),z\ge 0\right\} $$ and I want to calculate $$\int_E z(x^2+y^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz.$$

It's better cylindrical or spherical change of coordinates?

Comment: I don't see any instances of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, but I *do* see several $(x^2+y^2)$'s.  So I'd go with cylindrical.

Comment: the final result is ${32 \over 9} \pi \sqrt{2}$?